# Erro quando chamo uma função, Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html, funções, onclick

Olá, estou realizando um projeto para estudo. Quando chamo a função, o código apresenta um erro.
A unica coisa que eu quero fazer nessa função é só trocar uma imagem pela outra quando clicar e assim também mudar a cor do fundo.

```
    <div class="content">
        <div class="textBox">
            <h2>That's What<br><span>I like</span></h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
            </p>
            <a href="#">View All Products</a>
        </div>        
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="./images/pepsi001.png" alt="pepsi">    
        </div>

    </div>

    <ul class="thumb">
        <li><img src="./images/pepsi001.png" onclick="imgSlider('pepsi001.png');changerBgColor('#0062be')"></li>
        <li><img src="./images/pepsi002.png" onclick="imgSlider('pepsi002.png');changerBgColor('#360c2c')"></li>
        <li><img src="./images/pepsi003.png" onclick="imgSlider('pepsi003.png');changerBgColor('#1e1e1e')"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="sci">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/instagram.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>

</section>

<script>
    function imgSlider(anything) {
        document.querySelector('.pepsi').src = anything;
    }

    function changerBgColor(color) {
        const sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
        sec.style.background = color;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: A lista HTML de produtos acabou sendo interpretada como uma lista da própria pergunta. Tente consertar a postagem para o código HTML aparecer.

Comment: Alteração feita.

Answer (score 1):

Na função *imgSlider*, você usou a classe *pepsi* para selecionar as imagens que devem ser trocadas. No entanto, não há nenhum item no HTML que tenha essa classe, e isso faz com que não seja possível encontrar os elementos, fazendo com com que o *browser* encontre apenas *null*.
Para que o código funcione, adicione o atributo *class="pepsi"* em todos os itens HTML que você quer que sofram a transformação.